# Adding a first and last class to Wordpress' widget contents

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress, I'm looking for some way to add a "last" and a "first" class to list items inside Wordpress widgets. The HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="widget-area">
<ul >
    <li class="widget_recent_comments">
        <h3 class="widget-title">Recent comments</h3>
        <ul id="recentcomments">
            <li class="recentcomments">Comment 1</li>
            <li class="recentcomments">Comment 2</li>
            <li class="recentcomments">Comment 3</li>
            <li class="recentcomments">Comment 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="widget_my_links">
        <h3 class="widget-title">My links</h3>
        <ul id="my-links">
            <li class="item">Link 1</li>
            <li class="item">Link 2</li>
            <li class="item">Link 3</li>
            <li class="item">Link 4</li>
            <li class="item">Link 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

In this example above i'd like to have first/last classes added to the li with "Comment 1", "Comment 4", "Link 1" and "Link 5".

Is there an easy workaround for this? (I don't want to do this with javascript)

Thank you.

Comment: Look for hooks into the WordPress widget output methods. I'm sure there should be at least one at the end before it spits everything out. Given your requirements it's the only option.

A really hacky way is to use output buffering to catch and re-process the output. But with any solution you will need to hook into the base widget class, since you want to update all of them.

I highly recommend the JavaScript solution, it's literally one line of jQuery, and it won't be slow either since it's a simple traversal and attribute operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing these lists are generated in a loop. So what you could do, is create a variable before you go into the loop, and set it's value to 1 ($i = 1). Than at the end of the loop, add one up ($i++). Now, where you want the first/last class to appear, you can do

```
<?php if($i == 1):
  echo ' first';
elseif( $i == $number_of_items )
  echo 'last';
endif;      
?>
```

At $i == $number_of_items, you are comparing the max with the current, so you know you have the last if the statement is true.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: The actual loop (or "the loop" as its called in wordpress) is in the wordpress-code, so im not able to change that.  I was more thinking of adding some kind of filter, but was hoping there was an easier solution.

Comment: No "the loop" is the file that loops over posts, and displays them in one way or another. The widgets are individual plugins or functions that can be altered of overwritten. Are you using wordpress' standard template? 'Cause than these lists are probably generated in sidebar.php, or a call to a function is made in sidebar.php. It is okay to edit sidebar.php. If a function is called, you can probably overwrite that function in functions.php, or copy the function to functions.php, alter and rename it, and call that function instead,

Comment: No @Jasper, WordPress generates these kinds of lists w/o any accessibility to it's loop on the part of the user in the way that you mean.

Comment: In that case the best suggestion I can come up with is write your own widget, but that might be a bit of an overkill. You could also consider using the css 3 pseudo classes :first-child and :last-child, and use boilerplate or something simular to get it to work in all browsers. This is not a method I prefer because you have to use a library to fix browser differences, but it does work rather good I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first-item is easy, just use

```
ul#my-list li:first-child {
    /* special styles */
}
```

It's not adding a class, but you can still style it. There is not a similar css rule for `:last-child` unfortunately

Comment: True. Problem is I need IE6 support, so it looks like im gonna go for the :first-child and do a javascript-hack specifically for IE6. Thanks for your input.